# Blocking Binomial Data (Bernoulli Trials)

Tags: generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, experiment-design, lsmeans

Imagine you have a colony of roaches and you want to compare the efficacies of two insecticides. On one day you apply insecticide A to 50 insects and record your "outcome" as "1" (died) or "0" (survived). You do the same to insecticide B. But you know that the specific insect cohort makes a difference as well, so you repeat the trial with a new cohort on a different day. Ideally this blocking factor, "cohort", would be treated as a random effect, but the experiment cannot feasibly be repeated with enough cohort trials to effectively model it as a random effect.

I want to know if, after controlling for the error attributable to "cohort", mean differences between treatments were still significant.

Because I am familiar with R, I will use that to describe what I have unsuccessfully tried:

I tried `mod1 <- glm(outcome ~ insecticide + cohort, data = df, family = binomial)`. Both `insecticide` and `cohort` were significant. Using `{emmeans}` I looked at `emmeans(ref_grid(mod1), specs = "insecticide", type = "response")` to look at the estimated marginal means of insecticide averaged over the mean of "cohort." I do not think this was the correct approach. Standard error estimates for insecticide treatments were far too small. Effectively (or so I think) the estimated marginal means pooled the data into 100 bernoulli trails per treatment rather than two series of grouped bernoulli trials.

How do I skin this cat?

Comment: For starters, your emmeans call has the wrong spec. Should be `emmmeans(mod1, "insecticide")`. You don't need to explicitly call ref_grid. emmeans uses the model, it does not re-analyze the data. So if your model is (right|wrong), your EMMs with be (right|wrong).

Comment: BTW, analyzing as if we had 100 trials per insecticide corresponds to omitting `cohort` from the model, and doing so would make the SEs *larger*, not smaller.

Comment: @RussLenth I apologize, I'm under some pressure from my company and wrote this post quite late last night at my home, away from my code. "treatment" is the correct specs argument and I edited my original post to reflect that. And of course you're right about not needing to call ref_grid, although the results are identical.

Comment: @RussLenth The benefit of a doubt please. There was nothing wrong with your original suggestion. I corrected my typo with another typo. In my code (which I know you cannot see) I specified the emmeans call as you originally suggested.

The takeaway I'm getting here is that, my careless typos aside, you agree that using estimated marginal means (assuming my model was correctly specified), is a reasonable approach to the problem I described?

Comment: apologies - please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to model `cohort` as a random effect, and that seems appropriate. But one tricky aspect is that variability of random effects also creates a bias when you back-transform to the response scale.

Here is what I would do:

```
library(lme4)
mod2 <- glmer(outcome ~ insecticide + (1|cohort), 
              data = df, family = binomial)
VarCorr(mod2)
# write down the estimate of SD(cohort intercept)

library(emmeans)
(EMM <- emmeans(mod2, "insecticide", type = "response",
            bias.adj = TRUE, sigma = <value you wrote down>)

pairs(EMM) # (assuming you want pairwise comparisons)
```

Comment: This approach will probably make the SEs larger than you had via `glm`, because it includes the variability of `cohort` (even if not bias-adjusted)

Comment: Many, many thanks! I hesitate to even attempt a mixed model of this data since we only have two levels of ```cohort```. If we do go that route, our data is actually nested with each level of experiment occurring in each level of cohort. I think we would want to specify the model as ```glmer(outcome ~ insecticide + (1|cohort/insecticide), data = df, family = binomial)```?

Comment: Also, thank you @RussLenth for writing the ```{emmeans}``` and ```{lsmeans}``` packages, among others. I, and others in my office have made frequent use of it. Consider me a bit starstruck!